# How to use WakeLock with "PowerManager.LOCATION_MODE_NO_CHANGE"?

Tags: android, location, wakelock, android-wake-lock, powermanager

I am trying to use

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.LOCATION_MODE_NO_CHANGE, "My Tag");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
```

in onCreate method of Activity. But it is crashing my app.
When I use

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
```

It works fine. (with PPARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK).

Answer (score 1):

a little bit late to answer ;p ... Have you tried something like `newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK or PowerManager.LOCATION_MODE_NO_CHANGE, "myTAG")`

Comment: Yup, I tried this and it helped me somehow. Btw thanks for your reply.